# Is my idea correct? "Prove that $(T-5I)^{n-1} (T-6I)^{n-1} = 0$"

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space. Suppose $T$ is in $L(V)$ such that 5
>   and 6 are eigenvalues of $T$ and that $T$ has no other eigenvalues.
>
> Prove that $(T-5I)^{n-1} (T-6I)^{n-1}= 0$

My thought process is the following: for the above to hold, the polynomial must be a multiple of the characteristic polynomial of $T.$

The characteristic polynomial of T is of the form $(z-5)^m  (z-6)^k$, where $m+k=n$

As $m,k > 1$, the highest value either of them can take is $n-1.$

Hence $(T-5I)^{n-1}(T-6I)^{n-1}$ is a multiple of the characteristic polynomial and therefore equals 0.

I feel like this proof is *too* straightforward and that I might be making some unfounded assumptions. Any comments appreciated!

Comment: It is correct, note that you use the theorem of Hamilton-Cayley.

Comment: Minor detail; it is true that $m,k\geq1$, but in general not that $m,k>1$.

Comment: @Servaes, correct, just a rushed write up on my part. Thanks for the comment & the answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $n=\dim V$, then your argument works. Be careful though; it is sufficient but not necessary that $(z-5I)^{n-1}(z-6I)^{n-1}$ is a multiple of the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $(z-5I)^{n-1}(z-6I)^{n-1}$ is a multiple of the *minimal* polynomial of $T$. By Cayley-Hamilton the characteristic polynomial is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, hence it is also sufficient for $(z-5I)^{n-1}(z-6I)^{n-1}$ to be a multiple of the characteristic polynomial.